# HP ALM and JMeter integration

Tags: jmeter, performance, hp-alm

Has anyone tried to Integrate HP ALM with JMeter? Very new to HP ALM so not sure on how to integrate it with JMeter.

On high level following functionality should work

1. trigger test with HP ALM
2. Execute test(test will run through JMeter)
3. Result should be uploaded on HP ALM

Any information regarding this would be helpful
Thanks

Comment: May be you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751103/running-jmeter-script-using-vbscript-as-automated-test-in-hp-alm) out.

Comment: Checked this link. It helps me solve step 1 but not able to think through any solution for step 2 and step 3 mentioned above